# How to get subprocess default/preset values/behaviour

Tags: python, stdin, stderr, dev-null

In this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273191/15459) I have explained how to check how many QGIS projects are open in a windows session.

Here is the shortened code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from os.path import basename
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox

def checkQgisProcesses(self):
    try:
        from subprocess import DEVNULL
    except ImportError:
        DEVNULL = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)

    res = subprocess.check_output('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq qgis-bin.exe" -v 2>NUL', stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, startupinfo = info)
    ...

def someOtherFunc(self):
    self.checkQgisProcesses()
    ...
```

The code uses `tasklist` from Windows to get information about all open windows and filters the QGIS window title.

I use this code within a function in a QGIS plugin.

There is another function in the plugin where I call multiple `subprocess` another time to make some calculations with another programm (`SAGA GIS`):

```
curv_PATH = plugin_pth + 'dem_curvature.bat'
subprocess.call(["C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", "/c", script_PATH], startupinfo = info)
subprocess.call(['gdalwarp', raster_dest_data + 'dem_gaussian.sdat', '-tr', cellsize, cellsize, '-r', 'bilinear', raster_dest_data + 'dem_res.tif' ], startupinfo = info)
subprocess.call(["C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", "/c", curv_PATH], startupinfo = info)
```

The problem is that these `subprocess` calls doesn't work anymore. I don't get a specific error in the QGIS python console.

When I comment `self.checkQgisProcesses()` it works again.

I think the problem lies within the `DEVNULL`, `stdin`, `stderr` parameters.

How can I set them back to default?

**UPDATE**

I wrongly thought the problem could be the `DEVNULL` declaration. Obviously the problem is the use of `subprocess.STARTUPINFO()`.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import os
from os.path import basename
import subprocess

SW_HIDE = 0
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE

def checkFirefoxProcesses():
    try:
        from subprocess import DEVNULL
    except ImportError:
        DEVNULL = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
    res = subprocess.check_output('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" -v 2>NUL', stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, startupinfo = info)
    print res

def helloWorldToText():
    subprocess.call(["C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", "/c", r"d:\\hello_world.bat"], startupinfo = info)

checkFirefoxProcesses()
helloWorldToText()
```

This is the code from `hello_world.bat`:

```
REM @ECHO OFF

ECHO Hello World! > d:\\hello_world.txt

PAUSE
```

The function `checkFirefoxProcesses()` looks for open `firefox` processes. To run through the example you have to open a `firefox` session. The function `helloWorldToText()` creates a text file from `ECHO` with the help of a BAT file.

The example doesn't creates the text file with the declaration of `startupinfo = info`. When I run the `subprocess` of function `helloWorldToText()` without `startupinfo = info` it works.

The case: running `checkFirefoxProcesses()` without `startupinfo = info` and running `helloWorldToText()` with `startupinfo = info` works.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that the declaration of `DEVNULL` in one function would affect subprocess calls elsewhere in the application. Can you simply this to a [mcve]?

Comment: @DanielPryden I tried my best to create a reproducible example. The problem is in my opinion the declaration of `subprocess.STARTUPINFO()`.

Comment: Yes, that seems very likely. Don't reuse a `STARTUPINFO` object: instead, you should make a new one each time you create any subprocess.

Comment: In my Python QGIS plugin I called `subprocess.call()` with `startupinfo = info` 14 times without problems, since I call `subprocess.check_output()` one time with `startupinfo = info` at first.  So, is there any dependency on using `STARTUPINFO` with different `subprocess` types/methods (call, check_output)?